# How to give permalink of page in a custom post type displayed using foreach loop

Tags: php, wordpress, href

I have a custom post type called services. In this i have a number of posts which are displayed on a page named services using for each loop.

this is ma services page code:

```
<?php get_header();
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status'=> 'publish', 'post_type' => 'services');
$services = get_posts( $args );
?>
<ul>
   <?php
       $i=1;
       foreach ($services as $values) {
              if($i%2==0){ 
   ?>
   <li>
       <div class="entry-title">
       <h2><a href=""><?php echo $values->post_title;?></a></h2>
       </div>
```

now each heading has a "a href" link which will redirect to its individual page.These pages are set in the PAGES post type.how can i pass the a href here.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_permalink/

Comment: I read the article but didnt quiet grasp it

Answer (score 0):

do this

```
<h2>
  <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_permalink($values->ID) ); ?>"><?php echo $values->post_title;?>
  </a>
</h2>
```

but why don't you go with traditional wordpress loop or you can simply do the following

```
<?php

global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status'=> 'publish', 'post_type' => 'services');

$services = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $services as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div class="entry-title">
       <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

see carefully that there is

```
setup_postdata( $post );
```

after `foreach ( $services as $post )`

Comment: this code onlu works if i need to display the single page of the title belonging in the same custom post type.

But i have created a different page in post type "PAGES" for each heading. AND  i want to pass that url here

Comment: this will display all the posts in `'post_type' => 'services'` as your query is set that way

Comment: yes it displays all the posts in my service post type ... but each post title has a different url which i want to redirect to its PAGE which is created in post type page ... as per yur code when i click the title it will only dispaly the same data in a different design as per single page.html

Comment: you mean there is another link to which you want to redirect each post?

Comment: create a `post meta` to store the url of the page or set the url in excerpt if not used and echo  the value in `href`, or use [advanced custom field](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-custom-fields/) to create a field that stores the url

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code like:

```
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php echo $values->post_title;?></a></h2>
```

Comment: Am sorry But it dosent seem to have any effect

Answer (score 0):

If you have created the post then why you want to create a page for all this same post.

If you have created a page with same post title name then you can change your query and display your page title there instead of the post title.

You need to do just create "service" name category for page post type. I know by default WordPress has no feature to create category so, You can install a plugin for that. There are so many plugins available for that like [Post Tags and Categories for Pages](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-tags-and-categories-for-pages/)

First of all install plugin and then just create category service and assign to all service related pages.

After that, you need to change your query like getting all page title with service category. See below:

```
   global $post;
$args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_status'=> 'publish', 'post_type' => 'page', 'category' => "YOUR CATEGORY ID",);

$services = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $services as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
    <div class="entry-title">
       <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
   </div>
<?php endforeach; 
wp_reset_postdata();?>
```

Hope you get my point and will helpful for you. Thanks.